# AVPlayer stops displaying video layer after several uses

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avplayer

I have an app that uses a collection view for a photo/video viewer. Each cell either displays an image cell or a video cell. The video cell is backed by AVPlayer and can either play streaming or local videos. Everything works great most of the time, however after what seems like a random amount of instances of the AVPlayer being created/destroyed it just stops showing the video. I can completely dealloc the view controller so all cells are for sure destroyed, open it back and it will still not show the video. The only thing that fixes it once it gets into this state is to kill and restart the app.

I have looked in every place I can think of. There are video tracks, play gets called, no errors etc..

Anyone deal with something like this before?

Comment: Could the media services daemon be crashing? You might register for the AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereLost notification and see if anything comes in. In any case it sounds like you may be overloading the daemon. Only a very limited number of videos can be shown at once (in some cases, just one).

Comment: @matt It does seem something like this is happening, however I just tested and that notification never is fired when I am able to recreate this